# using sed command to get after a /

Tags: sed, filenames

I want to use sed for extracting the file name after the last occurrence of /.

For example 
    /usr/bin/file.txt
and the output should be 
    file.txt

Comment: Is this an assignment/homework? I can't see any other reason as to why you absolutely need to use `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `sed`; you can use the [`basename`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/basename-invocation.html) command to return the filename part:

```
> basename /usr/bin/top
top
```

If you definitely want to use `sed`, this works with GNU sed 4.5:

```
sed 's/^.*\/\([^/]\+\)$/\1/'
```

Comment: no need to anchor the `.*` to the beginning -- it's greedy and will match as much as it can; ditto the trailing part